# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 iis configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-6, windows-server-2008-r2

I am hosting a site on IIS. My site perfectly runs on localhost. But when I run it on Windows Server 2008 it do not load my resources.

All the time it displays this error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal server error).

This error come on Chrome. If I browse it on IE then there is only one error that is

> Script5: Access is denied

Please see the pics for reference.

[image]

Comment: It may requires permission to access over the root folder. you can do this by allowing all by selecting everyone option from security tab.

Comment: ok let me try it.

Comment: Rahul Hendawe, it did not work.